# PlusCal: Why does fair algorithm still stutter?

Tags: tla+, pluscal

I've used PlusCal to model a trivial state machine that accepts strings matching the regular expression `(X*)(Y)`.

```
(*--fair algorithm stateMachine
variables
    state = "start";

begin

Loop:    
while state /= "end" do
    either
        \* we got an X, keep going
        state := "reading"
    or
        \* we got a Y, terminate
        state := "end"
    end either;
end while;


end algorithm;*)
```

Even though I've marked the algorithm `fair`, the following temporal condition fails because of stuttering ... the model checker allows for the case where the state machine absorbs an `X` and then simply stops at `Loop` without doing anything else ever again.

```
MachineTerminates == <>[](state = "end")
```

What does fairness actually mean in the context of a simple process like this one?  Is there a way to tell the model checker that the state machine will never run out of inputs and thus will always terminate?

Comment: Is this your EXACT specification and model, with nothing else different? It SHOULD be terminating, but for an extremely specific reason that's unrelated to the reason this normally _wouldn't_ terminate. (As in, I can explain why in 99.9% of similar cases it wouldn't terminate, but this LOOKS like the 0.1% it should.)

Comment: @Hovercouch -- yeah, I pasted the code directly from my repo here:  https://github.com/lostbearlabs/tiny-tlaplus-examples/blob/master/state-machine/StateMachine.tla
Only difference is that I excluded the "define" section where the invariants are specified.

Comment: @Hovercouch -- also, would love to understand the 99.9% reason even if this one does (should?) magically slip through...  I am very pre-grok with this stuff...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so this is very weird and *should* pass, but not for the the reason you'd think. To understand why, we first have to talk about the "usual" definition of fairness, then the technical one.

Weak fairness says that if an action is never disabled, it will eventually happen. What you probably expected is the following:

1. Loop could pick "end" but doesn't.
2. Loop could pick "end" but doesn't. This happens some arbitrary number of times.
3. Since Loop is fair*, it is forced to pick "end".
4. We're done.

But that's not the case. Fairness, in pluscal, is at the label level. It doesn't say anything about what happens in the label, just that label *itself* must happen. So this is a perfectly valid behavior:

1. Because loop is never disabled, it eventually happens. It picks "reading".
2. Because loop is never disabled, it eventually happens. It picks "reading".
3. Because loop is never disabled, it eventually happens. It picks "reading".
4. This keeps going forever.

This corresponds to you inputting a string of infinite length, consisting only of X's. If you only want finite strings, you have to explicitly express that, either as part of the spec or as one of the preconditions to your desired temporal property. For example, you could make your temporal property `state = "end" ~> Termination`, you could model the input string, you could add a count for "how many x's before the y", etc. This gets out of what's actually wrong and into what's good spec design, though.

That's the *normal* case. But this is a very, **very** specific exception to the rule. That's because of how "fairness is defined". Formally, `WF_vars(A) == <>[](Enabled <<A>>_v) => []<><<A>>_v`. We usually translate that as

> If the system is always able to do A, then it will keep on doing A.

That's the interpretation I was using up until now. But it is wrong in one very big way. `<<A>>_vars == A /\ (vars' /= vars)`, or "A happens and `vars` changes. So our definition actually is

> If the system is always able to do A *in a way that changes its state*, then it will keep on doing A *in a way that changes its state*.

Once you have `pc = "Loop" /\ state = "reading"`, doing `state := "reading"` does *not* change the state of the system, so it doesn't count as `<<Next>>_vars`. So `<<Next>>_vars` didn't actually happen, but by weak fairness it must eventually happen. The only way for `<<Next>>_vars` to happen is if the loop sets `state := "reading`, which allows the while loop to terminate.

This is a pretty unstable situation. Any slight change we make to the spec is likely to push us back into more familiar territory. For example, the following spec will not terminate, as expected:

```
variables
    state = "start";
    foo = TRUE;        
begin
Loop:    
while state /= "end" do
    foo := ~foo;
    either
        \* we got an X, keep going
        state := "reading"
    or
        \* we got a Y, terminate
        state := "end"
    end either;
end while;
end algorithm;*)
```

Even though `foo` doesn't affect the rest of the code, it allows us to have `vars' /= vars` without having to update `state`. Similarly, replacing `WF_vars(Next)` with `WF_pc(Next)` makes the spec fail, as we can reach a state where `<<Next>>_pc` is disabled (aka any state where `state = "reading"`).

*Loop isn't fair, the total algorithm is. This can make a big difference in some cases, which is why we spec. But it's easier in this case to talk about Loop, as it's the only action.

Comment: Why did you say `Loop isn't fair, the total algorithm is` ?
If we suppose `Next == ActionA /\ ActionB`, then, what is the difference between `WF_vars(Next)` and `WF_vars(ActionA) /\ WF_vars(ActionB)` ?

Comment: @devio If `ActionB` is always enabled, then the sequence of actions `<<ActionA, ActionA, ActionA, ActionA, ...>>` would satisfy `WF_vars(Next)` but not `WF_vars(ActionA) /\ WF_vars(ActionB)` .